# GraphQL - fetch a field conditionally

Tags: graphql

Imagine that I have a following query (I am using Apollo):

```
const userQuery = gql`
    query {
      user {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  `;
```

I want to fetch `name` field only if some condition is met (let's say variable `shouldFetchName` is `true`). How should I approach this and what is the best practice?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can pass a variable to your query and use a Directive to fetch a field conditionally, like `name @include(if: $shouldFetchName)`.

See [the docs for Directives](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#directives).

Comment: This a partial solution, with "include", the database still makes the calculations to return "name", but the "include" just filters the response to the client.
So this will not result in a faster query.
Do you know a better solution ?

Comment: If the `@include` directive evaluates to false then the `name` resolver will not be called. What your database does is entirely up to you: Apollo Server doesn't know or care about that part. If you want to dynamically build SQL queries from your GraphQL queries, you may like https://github.com/join-monster/join-monster.